# join two lists of objects, taking the first matching object from the second list

Tags: c#

I have two lists: Owners and Permits.  They match on OwnerID, and come from two database tables of the same name

I have a ViewModel: ViewModel, which holds a list of Owners and a list of Permits

I have this select statement which selects all owners and every permit associated with that owner:

```
var list = from o in owners
join p in permits
on o.LandOwnerID equals p.Landowner into tbl
from p in tbl.ToList()
where o.RecordDeleted == false
orderby o.ModifiedDate descending
select new ViewModel
{
    Owner = o,
    Permit = p
};
```

With this query, my results look like this:

```
Owner1     Permit1
Owner1     Permit2
Owner1     Permit3
Owner2     Permit4
Owner3     Permit5
Owner3     Permit6
Owner3     Permit7
```

What I would like to end up with is this:

```
Owner1     Permit1
Owner2     Permit4
Owner3     Permit5
```

If this were in a SQL query, I would do a groupby, an orderby, and a select top 1 permit.

How do I do this when comparing two lists?  The groupby option doesn't exist. -- clarification: there is no GroupBy in my autocomplete options when I try adding it anywhere within the query.

Comment: I'd join owners to permits grouped by owner, and then grab `.First()` from the permits group for each owner. When you say "the groupby option doesn't exist", can you clarify that?

Comment: Feel free to add the SQL query to showcase what you want.

Comment: How to group: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325306/1141432